# How do I use javascript to "get" a known, relative subdirectory on github?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, github, file-not-found

I'm hosting a webpage on github: https://jaitnium.github.io/popularLocationsDemo/flickrTest.html.

I'm trying to "get" a known subdirectory using:

```
$.get("mapData/2015/May/.", function(data) {
     ...
}
```

but I'm getting a "404 file not found" error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET https://jaitnium.github.io/popularLocationsDemo/mapData/2015/May/ 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I determine the correct path to "get" the subdirectory? Does github have a special way of doing this because this works when my website is hosted by google? I've also tried getting:

```
https://github.com/Jaitnium/Jaitnium.github.io/tree/master/popularLocationsDemo/mapData/2015/May
```

and

```
https://jaitnium.github.io/popularLocationsDemo/mapData/2015/May/
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t “read” a directory. If you were expecting to list its contents, GitHub (and may other websites) don’t allow this. Instead, request a file:

```
$.get("mapData/2015/May/Paris_May_2015.json", function(data) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted you, but what do you mean by "you can't read a directory"? I'm able to read a directory locally and when I host my site on goggle. In this case though, I'm not able to find the directory I'm specifying.

Comment: @Jaitnium does that look better?

Comment: I'm following your example exactly, but I'm getting a mixed content exception: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jaitnium.github.io/popularLocationsDemo/flickrTest.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://jaitnium.github.io/popularLocationsDemo/mapData/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @Jaitnium Are you loading jQuery over HTTPS?

Comment: @J F Yes I am loading Jquery over https.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121977/discussion-between-j-f-and-jaitnium).

Comment: I was able to get my webpage working using the approach we discussed. For anyone interested, I created a python script to create an "index.json" which contains the folder structure of mapData.